Xero If-Modified-Since filter doesn't work
I tried to filter budget and set the http request header ('If-Modified-Since') with a future datetime. I still get all budget rather than the empty. Can anybody help me with the issue?
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",     config.AccessToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("xero-tenant-id", config.TenantID);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}


I tested the 'if-modified-since' filter. Actually there was only 1 budget record and Its 'UpdatedDateUTC' was '2024-04-11 07:39:03.070'. When I read it without the filter, I got the record correctly. However, when I set the http header attribute with date (some later time), It still sent me the record! It should return me empty as there was none after that time! Did I miss something?

Ok, according to these docs it should work but I can tell you that not all Xero API endpoints behave the same. For Budgets specifically, you can try the DateFrom and DateTo query parameters instead

I'd get in touch with Xero support if the API isn't behaving as advertised
